# Python Recursive Fibonacci "Tree" Output

Tags: python, recursion, sequence, turtle-graphics, fibonacci

**Summary:** To be frank, this is a homework assignment, but I've already completed what the assignment originally asked of me. At this point, I'm challenging myself to build additional functionality into the program. I want to build a *visual* Fibonacci "tree" when [n] number is given.

**For example:**

User inputs 6 for n, result 8 is given, but a tree is also printed to the console or perhaps visualized using Turtle. (see figure 1)

So far I've created a class that takes parent(n), child1(n-1), and child2(n-2) as parameters, and some clunky code to output them in essentially triangles that print out in groups of 3. I've not figure out, however, to make a visual similar to this example below.

figure 1)

```
                                           fib(6)
                                          /      \
                                         /        \
                           fib(4) - - fib(5)   fib(4) - - fib(3)
                         /      |       |         |       |     \
                        /       |       |         |       |      \
          fib(2) - - fib(3)  fib(2)   fib(3)   fib(2)   fib(1)   fib(2) - - 1
           |          |     |        /    \        |      |       
           |          |     |       /      \       |      |
           1      fib(1)    1    fib(2)   fib(1)   1      1
                 /              /               \
                /              /                 \
               1              1                   1


def __init__(self, child1, child2, parent):
    self.firstchild = child1
    self.secondchild = child2
    self.parent = parent

def show(self):
    if self.firstchild == 1 and self.secondchild == 0:
        print("            [fib" + str(self.parent) + "]")
        print("           /      \\")
        print("          /        \\")
        print("        [" + str(self.secondchild) + "]        [" + str(self.firstchild) + "] <-- End of branch")

    else:

        print("            [fib" + str(self.parent) + "]")
        print("           /      \\")
        print("          /        \\")
        print("      [fib" + str(self.secondchild) + "]      [fib" + str(self.firstchild) + "]")
```

**What I've Tried/Thought of:** I've tried writing the branch object show output to a file instead to manipulate it there, but it gets so eclectic and tight-spaced that I'm not sure if it's realistic to do it that way. I've thought of using the Turtle module, like I mentioned before, maybe in some way? I've also played around with the idea of linked lists (node class) but with multiple associations to a node to build a tree? Looking for some input.

**My Question:** I already have a working recursive Fibonacci program, but my question is how I would go about also printing out a visual representation of the output of a Fibonacci sequence for n number. I'm basically looking to output my ASCII Fibonacci tree I've given as an example above.

Comment: What is your question?  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  You've posted a partial description of your project -- but no code, no demonstrable problem, and no specific question.

Comment: You need to be more specific and clear in your questioning.

Comment: The post wizard was breaking the formatting on my figure that I was trying to provide so when the question was originally posted some of what I had written was missing. Kind of annoying that I've been on this site for less than 20 minutes as a user and I already have a down vote...

Comment: I also am not sure what your question is, but if you use the "edit" button and clarify I'd be happy to take a crack at answering it.  Cool ASCII tree btw!

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for the input. I've edited my submission again to hopefully clear things up.